# Google Listen doesn't register Play/Pause commands after upgrade to ICS

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, google-listen

I have been using Google Listen as podcast player on Samsung Galaxy SII paired with Plantronics BackBeat 903. It worked well until I upgraded to ICS and now the play and pause buttons won't be registered by Google Listen. The play/pause button only unmutes/mutes the sound while the podcast continues to play. This was not the case prior to upgrade. Anyone else noticed this and have a fix for this?

Comment: It gets even worse on Jelly Bean: Listen has become totally unusable after the upgrade, pressing play only skips back 3 seconds. I haven't found any way to get it to play anything at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a few apps, I settled on [KiesCast by Samsung](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sec.android.app.podcast).

**Pros**

- Simple intuitive UI.
- Has almost all settings that one would generally need without being overly complex.
- Play speed from 0.5x to 2.0x.
- Skip interval is configurable.
- Very good podcast search.
- Plays videos as well.

**Cons**

- Sometimes CPU use goes thru the roof.
- Loses the play position sometimes after the podcast is stopped.
- Ad supported. Can't complain as it is free but company like Samsung should be able to support it without ads. Moreover, while listening the screen can shut off and thus no ads. In video play mode I haven't seen any ads as I usually watch video full screen.